# Build slow down on VS.NET 2010 after installing VS.NET 2011 (Developer Preview Edition)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-time

I installed Visual Studio 11 (developer preview edition) last week, since then, the build speed of the previous version (VS 10).
- using diagnostic build the "GenerateResource" task takes much longer than other processes (about a minute!)
- checked all .resx files for version conflict, all are 4.0.0.0 (project is developed using .NET 4.0)

does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Looks like someone thinks this question is not 'research effort or useful...". well, I wish him/her the best similar thing happen while he is working on an enterprise solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just asked MS about the problem on Connect, apparently it is a problem with side-by-side installing Visual Studio .NET 11 Developer Preview Edition with Visual Studio 2010.

They told me the problem will be solved in the final release.

Comment: Good to know, I'll stick with running it in a VM then for now :)